# EXCEL Distribute values in a column based on conditions

Tags: excel, formula

I need a formula to distribute values based on conditions.

In below (attached) image of excel sheet are two tables. Table-1 where i need data to be filled from Table-2. Formula should look in to table-2 and pick a value of 88587+HAWA+Jan and distribute in to Table-1 88587+HAWA+Jan column and so on till Dec...

Example:

In Table-2 formula pick 88587+HAWA+Jan (value is 71,405) than search in Table-1 for 88587+HAWA+Jan (in my case there are two matches to be filled with C3 and C6) now divide the value with count of matches 71,405/2= 35,703. Now formula put that 35,703 into C3 and C6.

Thanks in advance

[image: Excel Data Image for Value Distribution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in C3 and copy over and down.

```
=SUMIFS(C$28:C$100000,$A$28:$A$100000,$A3,$B$28:$B$100000,$B3)/COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$24,$A3,$B$3:$B$24,$B3)
```

Comment: Thank you Scott that's exactly what i want.

Comment: @AXL please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.